# Android Infinite Auto Image Slider Using View Pager 2 issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, slider, android-viewpager2

In my app there's a viewPager containing the images of products, and I've created the logic to auto-slide images every 3 seconds shows an image and if the user touches the screen it should stop sliding, and when it reaches the final image the slider restarts from the first image again, and so on, The problem is sometimes the slider hangs and continue moving from the first image to the last one faster,

**The following GIF describes the problem**

[image]

the full code

```
     companion object {
            private const val DELAY_TIME: Long = 3000
            private const val PERIOD_TIME: Long = 3000

            private var currentPage = 0
        }

        private var timer: Timer? = null
        private var sliderHandler: Handler? = null
        private var update: Runnable? = null
        private lateinit var onPageChangeCallback: OnPageChangeCallback
        private var arrangedList = arrayListOf<SliderModel>()


        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        fun setBannerSliderViewPager(sliderModelList: List<SliderModel>) {
            currentPage = 2
            if (timer != null) {
                timer!!.cancel()
            }

            for (x in sliderModelList.indices) {
                arrangedList.add(x, sliderModelList[x])
            }
            arrangedList.add(0, sliderModelList[sliderModelList.size - 2])
            arrangedList.add(1, sliderModelList[sliderModelList.size - 1])
            arrangedList.add(0, sliderModelList[0])
            arrangedList.add(1, sliderModelList[0])
            val sliderAdapter = SliderAdapter()

            sliderAdapter.asyncListDiffer.submitList(arrangedList)

            binding.bannerSliderViewPager.apply {
                adapter = sliderAdapter
                clipToPadding = false
                clipChildren = false
                offscreenPageLimit = 3
            }

//            binding.bannerSliderViewPager.setPageMargin(20);
//            binding.bannerSliderViewPager.getChildAt(0).setOverScrollMode(RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

            val compositePageTransformer = CompositePageTransformer()
            compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(MarginPageTransformer(20))
            compositePageTransformer.addTransformer { page: View, position: Float ->
                val r = 1 - abs(position)
                page.scaleY = 0.85f + r * 0.15f
            }
            binding.bannerSliderViewPager.setPageTransformer(compositePageTransformer)
            binding.bannerSliderViewPager.currentItem = currentPage

            onPageChangeCallback = object : OnPageChangeCallback() {

                override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                    super.onPageSelected(position)
                    currentPage = position
                }

                override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                    super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state)
                    if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        pageLopper(arrangedList)
                    }
                }
            }
            binding.bannerSliderViewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(onPageChangeCallback)
            startBannerSliderShow(sliderModelList)
            binding.bannerSliderViewPager.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
                pageLopper(arrangedList)
                timer!!.cancel()
                if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    startBannerSliderShow(arrangedList)
                }
                false
            }
        }

        

        private fun startBannerSliderShow(sliderModelList: List<SliderModel>?) {

//            isFirstRun = currentPage == 0;
            sliderHandler = Handler()
            update = Runnable {
                if (currentPage >= sliderModelList!!.size) {
                    currentPage = 0
                }
                binding.bannerSliderViewPager.setCurrentItem(
                    currentPage++,
                    true
                )
            }
            timer = Timer()
            timer!!.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
                override fun run() {
                    sliderHandler!!.post(update!!)
                }
            }, DELAY_TIME, PERIOD_TIME)
        }

        private fun stopBannerSlideShow() {
            timer!!.cancel()
        }

        private fun pageLopper(sliderModelList: List<SliderModel>?) {
            if (currentPage == sliderModelList!!.size - 2) {
                currentPage = 2
                binding.bannerSliderViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage, false)
            }
            if (currentPage == 1) {
                currentPage = sliderModelList.size - 3
                binding.bannerSliderViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage, false)
            }
        }
```